# How do I stop losing messages on MQ

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, mq

I am writing a Java application, running in a LINUX environment, that does transactions on an MQ using SYNCPOINT. It uses Websphere MQ Java Classes to interact with the MQ service. What I am doing in my code is the following (pseudo):

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQConstants.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQConstants.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;

MQMessage message = new Message();
queue.get(message, gmo);

// process the message, save to database

databaseConnection.commit();
queueManager.commit();
```

I basically grab the message, process it, persist to database, then call a commit on the queueManager. The process listens for a message on TIBRV in order to do a graceful shutdown.

I've been testing the process to make sure no messages are lost. I place 20k messages on a queue, then run the process. I perform a graceful shutdown call in the middle of processing. I then compare the amount of messages on the queue versus the amount of messages in database. When a graceful shutdown occurs via TIBRV message, the number of MQ messages + the number of DB messages = total messages originally on the queue.

However, when I do a `kill` or `kill -9`, I see that a message is lost. I always end up with a result of 19999 total messages.

Is there a way I can investigate how I am losing this message? Is there anything that occurs on the Websphere App Server that I would need to be aware of?

Comment: is it possible that there is some outstanding transaction which needs to be rolled back before you check the totals?

Comment: From what I've observed, if I read messages off of MQ, then the process dies without committing, then when the connection is closed, MQ rolls the messages back. Have you've seen something similar?

Comment: I realized that there is an outstanding transaction occurring. Websphere actually won't rollback the last message when my process terminates abnormally, and the connection is severed. What I'm doing now is opening the queue for browsing, and I pull the message out at the end of my transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to expect the numbers to reconcile when using single-phase commit.  The program will always be between the WMQ and DB Commit call or else between the DB and WMQ Commit call when you kill it.

What you are asking for would require 2-Phase (XA) Commit.  For WMQ, 2PC would require the application to be using bindings mode and for WMQ to be the resource coordinator.  You would then call MQBEGIN, execute your WMQ and DB updates, then call MQCOMMIT.  This way both the WMQ and DB transactions would succeed or fail together.

Comment: Pretty much what I would have said except that WAS would be the transaction provider.

Comment: We looked at two-phase commit. Unfortunately management did not agree to using it. They considered the changes too much effort. We concluded that committing first on DB, then on MQ, is a better alternative. Better to have message duped than to lose the message entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting or MQ in bindings mode or client mode?  In my experience, transactions didn't work out of the box in client mode, but they did in bindings mode.

Comment: I am connecting using TRANSPORT_MQSERIES as my connection, and using MQGMO_SYNCPOINT under my get options. If I connect in bindings mode, how will that affect my code's workflow above? Will Wepshere automatically rollback the last transaction when the connection is lost?

Comment: Using TRANSPORT_MQSERIES means that you could be connecting in either bindings or client, depending on whether or not you've set the hostname.  Source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.java.doc/com/ibm/mq/constants/CMQC.html

Have you set the host name?  Is the queue manager running on the same host as WebSphere App Server or a different host?